# Why doesn't alias work in AIX (Korn shell, .profile)?

Tags: shell, ksh, alias, aix, profile

I have these files in my home directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x    3 meuser staff           256 Oct 12 13:11 .
drwxr-xr-x  102 bin      bin            4096 Sep 30 12:28 ..
-rw-------    1 meuser staff          5349 Oct 11 20:44 .bash_history
-rwx------    1 meuser staff           466 Jun 26 22:12 .profile
-rw-------    1 meuser staff          7074 Oct 12 13:11 .sh_history
drwx------    2 meuser staff           256 Aug 16 15:28 .ssh
```

My default shell is the Korn shell. When I tried to put an alias into `.profile` like this:

```
alias l='ls -lrt'
```

and tried to run it after relogin:

```
$ l
ksh: l:  not found.
```

How to make this alias work?

Comment: What happens when you run `. ./.profile`?

Comment: Are you typing `l` in response to your `$ ` shell prompt, or are you typing `$l`?

Answer (score 2):

`.profile` is only read at login. Later modifications do not affect the current environment. You have to reload `.profile` by means of:

- sourcing the file: `. .profile` (affects the *current* shell, not *all* shells)
- `su -l <user>` (new login)
- logout + login

Comment: That does not seem to work. I changed my default shell to bash and relogin, and then it worked. So it is somehow related to korn shell.

Comment: @jrara Try adding `-l` to provide an login environemnt.

Answer (score 2):

It does work.

The only difference I can see with my own .profile are the double quotes:

`alias l="ls -l"`

That line works for me in AIX with ksh as the shell.

Regarding the disconection and reconection... are you sure the default shell is ksh? Check your user in /etc/passwd.

Comment: Note that the question shows an error message coming from `ksh`.

Comment: @G-Man My "It does work" in the answer means alias works in AIX (Read the title of the question). The rest of the answer explains why it didn't work in his case.

Answer (score 1):

The `.profile` is not your shell configuration file, it's your login session *settings file*. It is only read by the shell started upon login, not other interactive shells started within your login session.

`ksh` has no dedicated customization file per-se, but it treats the `$ENV` variable as a path to a customization file for interactive shell sessions.

So you'd add something like:

```
ENV="$HOME/.kshrc" export ENV
```

to your `~/.profile` and:

```
alias 'l=ls -lrt'
```

to your `~/.kshrc`.

The change would only take effect at the next login.

Answer (score 0):

The aliases work in AIX with Korn Shell.

Put some commands at the end of your `/etc/profile` like:

```
export PS1="`hostname`# "
alias ll="/usr/bin/ls -lF $*"
alias h="history 50"
```

If you want these variables set inside your environment, launch:

```
. /etc/profile
```